# From ... In ... Select in C#

Tags: c#, linq, performance

Are there any disadvantages or performance slowdowns related to the use of expressions like

```
from i in Enumerable.Range(1, Math.Min(strTexto.Length, tamMax) + 1)
                select Tuple.Create(strTexto.Substring(0, i - 1), strTexto.Substring(i - 1))
```

in C#? Is it preferable to build "hard-coded queries" like

```
foreach (Int32 IntTmp in SomeListWithTheRange)
    SomeListWithTheTuples.Add(new Tuple<String, String> (strTexto.Substring(0, i - 1), strTexto.Substring(i - 1)))
```

?

While the first one seems more readable at first glance, I have noticed that this kind of queries can get very slow... For instance, the first query takes 11ms to perform, while the second one takes only 1ms. Am I right? Just want to make sure since I need to implement lots of these kind of queries.

Comment: from..in..select is not C# but LINQ? Additional references may be needed.

Comment: @Bolu: You can't exactly say something is LINQ but not C# or vice versa. LINQ isn't really a separate language from C#, VB or other .NET programming languages. I get your point though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach will perform just as well as the second. When you say that you "have noticed that this kind of queries can get very slow" - could you provide more details? You can certainly write slow LINQ queries, but that's a matter of using LINQ appropriately.

Note that your two code samples aren't equivalent at the moment at all - the first just builds a query, but doesn't use it at all. Your second seems to be calling `Concat` repeatedly, which *will* be slow when you iterate over it, as you'll end up with an awful lot of iterators.

If you could explain what you're actually trying to do, that would help a lot.

Comment: In the method where I am using this query, I have the ''return'' keyword just before the query so that it will return the results in an enumerable fashion. There's however another function, where I use ''Concat'' four times, each of which has a query of the kind inside it. Can that make things slower?

Comment: @Miguel: Again, you'd have to give more details. It's very hard to talk about performance based on sketchy details. Calling Concat 4 times probably won't be too bad, but you *will* have 4 levels of indirection.